# Alternatives to HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I don't like some of the design decisions made in HtmlAgilityPack:

- When using `SelectNodes`, if no nodes are found, it returns `null` rather than an empty set, so you can't just `foreach` over it without a null check.
- When trying to select children with `node.SelectNodes` it actually searches from the document root unless you use `descendant::` which is not obvious nor expected behavior at all, IMO.
- `HtmlDocument.Load` doesn't return the root node, which is what you'd want 99% of the time, I think

You might disagree with that of course, but that's not the point. I'm looking for something *different*. Something that behaves a little more expected, or something that uses jQuery syntax would be even better. Suggestions?

Comment: For the examples you've given, it should be fairly easy to alter the behaviour to that which you desire. Since HtmlAgilityPack is open source, have you considered taking a local fork and making those changes?

Comment: For the time being I've just wrapped it with my own functions, but still. If there's something else out there a little more aligned with my philosophies, I'm not going to waste my efforts :) I only dabble in HTML parsing once in awhile for small projects, so I don't think it's worth my time to overhaul it to be the way I think it ought to be.

Comment: i hope it is works for you, http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/

Comment: [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) is a jQuery port for .NET 4

Answer (score 4):

Started project called [SharpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-query/)

Currently supports ID, class, tag, and attribute selectors.

```
a
a[href]
a[href^=http://stackoverflow.com]
.class
#id
```

**Update:** I'm not maintaining this project, sorry. [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) has recent updates (as of July 2013), but I don't have any experience using it.

Comment: I voted for SharpQuery + HTMLAgilityPack to merge a long time ago. Cos the HTML parser and DOM structure should be distinctly different from the query engine... Also, HTMLAgilityPack supports multiple query methods - XPath, LINQ and DOm traversal. SharpQuery on top of that would be awesome

Comment: Oh, wait u just started that project? I proposed joining a different project that does the exact same thing as SharpQuery... lemme find it

Comment: FOund it - http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/ and here's my merge request http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=76383

Comment: @CVertex: Could have mentioned Fizzler before I started this project :p I just added a neat regex selector `a[href %= /caseInsensitive/i]`

Comment: Anyway, SharpQuery is just a set of extension methods that work on `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>`, so it should play pretty nicely with HtmlAgilityPack. Might make it based on `IXPathNavigable` instead if I can figure out how... then it should work with any XML document.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just parsing the html, another option might be SgmlReader. 
If you're modifying the html, not so much.
Don't recall how it behaves with respect to the issues you raised,but it worth checking out.

Comment: As far as I can see, that library only converts malformed HTML into valid HTML... it says nothing about xpath/querying/traversing the DOM tree. I don't need to modify the document, but I *do* need to query it.

Comment: It turns it into valid xml in the form of an XmlDocument. Then you can call one of the XmlDocument.CreateNavigator() overloads to get an XPathNavigator object to perform xpath queries.